# Conditionally Filtering Out Rows based on 2 Parameters in w/ Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table similar to the one attached below:

[image]

What I would like to do, using power query, is conditionally filter out (remove) rows where CenterNum = 1101 and DepCode = 257. I figured `Table.SelectRows()`  would work but it doesn't and the query just returns, `this table is empty`. The `#"Expanded AccountLookup"` ,in my formula below, is referencing the power query applied step before the one I am trying to create. I'm hoping to get some input on how to remove rows based on these two paramters.

`= Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded AccountLookup", each [CostCenterNumber] = "1111001" and [NoteTypeCode] = "257")`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t post a screenshot so it is hard to tell if the column format is text or numerical but try removing the quotes around the numbers

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded AccountLookup", each [CostCenterNumber] = 1111001 and [NoteTypeCode] = 257)
```

If that doesn't work, check the actual column names against what you are using, especially for case (upper/lower) and leading/trailing spaces. The best way to do that is to temporarily rename it, and look at the code for the  "from name"